# Behaviour of array during recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int count;
vector<char*> ans;
char result[1000];   //result will store the current subsequence
void printAllSubsequences(char str[], int beg, int res_index) {
    if(str[beg] == '\0') {  // if you reach end of string, print the result(i.e.,one of the subsequences). Recursion quits after encountering the last element in the given string str
        result[res_index] = '\0';
        ++count;
        cout<<result<<' ';
        ans.push_back(result);
        return;
    }

    printAllSubsequences(str, beg+1, res_index);
    result[res_index] = str[beg];
    printAllSubsequences(str, beg+1, res_index+1);
}
int main() {
    char str[1000];   //str is the string whose permutations we have to find
    cin >> str;
    char result[1000];
    printAllSubsequences(str, 0, 0);
    cout<<count<<endl;
    for(vector<char*>::iterator ii = ans.begin(); ii!=ans.end(); ++ii){
        cout<<(*ii)<<' ';
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

When I give an input as

```
abcd
```

I get the following as output

```
 d c cd b bd bc bcd a ad ac acd ab abd abc abcd 16
 abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd
```

So, the first line returns the subsequences; great! 
For, the second if I store the same in a vector and then try to print it out, it gives me the same string over and over again. Where could the implementation be possibly going wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you expecting as result?

Comment: Use std::string instead of char arrays.

Comment: You know that you are not working on copies of the arrays?

Comment: @VidorVistrom . result stores the current subsequence being worked at.

Comment: Show a sample input and the expected output

Comment: A pass by value *is* a copy. Arrays are passed by reference.

Comment: @Aryan `vector<char*> ans;` -- One of the worst code smells in C++.  Unless you have a compelling reason (yes there are reasons, but not anything for what you're trying to achieve) , use `vector<std::string>`..

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can bet he switched from c to c++ recently without a good resource

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where could the implementation be possibly going wrong?

Here:

```
vector<char*> ans;
```

**Explanation:** You have created a vector of a pointer. Since every time you push the same pointer in the array so once the pointed memory output gets changed it will change the output of already pushed entries as well.

To fix the issue use `std::string` instead of `char array`